# Hiding items after a period of time [PHP/MySQL]

Tags: php, mysql, time, html

I want that items hide after the time expired, only today and future items would be shown.

I have code like that now but it doesn't work:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE closing_date >= CURRENT_DATE()");
$numrow = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

In the MYSQL I have closing_date in that format:

> sample: 2014-07-03 20:11:26

So now if time expire item would not be shown on page.

The code don't want work I had tryed many solutions but none didn't work :(

Timeformat must stay same as it is.

Thanks for help!

Comment: doesn't work **HOW**? This query fails? you get errors? You get wrong results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `CURRENT_DATE()` with `NOW()`

Comment: Great. Good luck with your project

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up `cronjob` that will run once a day or every few minutes that will run a script which will hide those items.

Your script should have this query:

```
UPDATE table SET hide_column = 1 WHERE closing_date < CURRENT_DATE()
```

If you dont want to hide anything and just grab data from today & after today you need to know what is the type of your closing_date column. If its `datetime` use `NOW()` to compare:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE closing_date >= NOW()
```

Answer (score 1):

CURRENT_DATE() just returns the date without time. that's why your code doesn't work as you want it to. you need to add the time, for example like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE closing_date >= CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', CURTIME())");
$numrow = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: it's basically the same but shows even better what the problem displayed in the question is.

Answer (score 0):

CURRENTDATE() is in the format 1997-12-15.    If your format is 2014-07-03 20:11:26, you could do something like this.

```
$currentDate = date(Y-m-d G:i:s);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE closing_date >=" . $currentDate);
$numrow = mysql_num_rows($result);
```